# How to hide percent complete in the progress bar of pgfgantt

Tags: pgfgantt

The percent complete is already shown in the color area. Is there a way to remove the text description?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far as a minimal working example.

Comment: If anyone wants to have the percentage but not the word "complete" this link may help
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558623/how-to-remove-the-text-after-the-calculate-percentage-in-a-pgfgantt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just leave the option `progress label text` empty:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid,
hgrid,
bar/.append style={fill=green},
bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},
progress=today,
today=6,
group progress label node/.append style={below=3pt}
]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{10} \\
\ganttbar[
bar progress label font=\color{green!25!black}\sffamily
]{Subtask 1}{1}{3} \\
\ganttbar[
progress label text={$\displaystyle\frac{#1}{100}$}
]{Subtask 2}{5}{12} \\
\ganttbar[
progress label text={}
]{Subtask 3}{5}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: progress label text]