# How to remove the text after the calculate percentage in a pgfgantt?

Tags: pgfgantt

I would like to remove the "complete" after the percentage in the progress label and keep the 60% only, without a digit.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Please find bellow a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    hgrid,
    bar/.append style={fill=green},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red}, progress=today,
    today=3,
    group progress label node/.append style={below=3pt} ]{1}{12}
    \gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{5} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\ganttset{progress label text={\pgfmathprint{round(#1)}\%}}`

Comment: Thank you it works very well but I have one more problem, it gives "60.0%". Is it possible to have no digit behind? Like "60%"

Thank you for your precious help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default setting for the `progress label text` key is `progress label text={#1\% complete}`. You can amend this to style the % completion as desired. Here we can write: `progress label text={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{#1}\%}`. This writes the text with just the number `#1` and `%` sign, without `complete`. The number is formatted using `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]` to give an integer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    hgrid,
    progress label text={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]{#1}\%},
    bar/.append style={fill=green},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red}, progress=today,
    today=3,
    group progress label node/.append style={below=3pt} ]{1}{12}
    \gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{5} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```